# Jquery - getting ID of DIV element clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following works fine and the ID of the button is displayed:

```
<input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" id="button1">
```

SCRIPT

```
$(".edit").click (function(){
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(buttonID);
}
```

But this does not with the ID buttonID as undefined:

```
<div id="button1" onclick="pickedID()">Edit</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
function pickedID() {
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(buttonID);
}
```

Why is this is and is there a way of getting the Div ID as I am trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `this` to the `function` when you call it, as in `<div id="button1" onclick="pickedID(this)">Edit</div>`

Then we can use it as below:

```
function pickedID(obj) {
    var buttonID = $(obj).attr('id');
    alert(buttonID);
}
```

So in this case, `obj` in `function pickedID(obj)` refers to `this` from `onclick="pickedID(this)"`

**demo**

```js
function pickedID(obj) {
    var buttonID = $(obj).attr('id');
    alert(buttonID);
}

$(".edit").click(function(){
    var buttonID = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(buttonID);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" id="button1">


<div id="button2" onclick="pickedID(this)">Edit</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to not use inline `onclick` handler. Much better to assign event handlers using jQuery.

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1">Edit</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `onclick`, it doesn't give you direct access to the attributes using `this`.

You can use `event` which will give you the mouse event handled and then you can retrieve the id.

In your case:

```js
function pickedID() {
    var buttonID = event.srcElement.id;
    console.log(buttonID);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1" onclick="pickedID()">Edit</div>
```

Or you can pass the id directly into the function:

```js
function pickedID(id) {
    console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1" onclick="pickedID(this.id)" data-id="2">Edit</div>
```